# Could anyone check if my relations between models are correct?

Tags: django, database, database-design, django-models

1. Some `Companies` represent some `PlaceTypes` (Gym, pool, etc.).
2. Different `PlaceTypes` have different `Criterias` for evaluation (Staff, cleanness, etc.)
3. Based on the Company's PlaceType it is necessary to apply appropriate criterias in order to evaluate this company

---

```
class Companies(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class PlaceTypes(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()  # Gym, pool, etc.
    company = models.ForeignKey(Companies)

class Criterias(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()  # Staff, cleanness, etc.
    place_type = models.ForeignKey(PlaceTypes)

class Ratings(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Companies)
    criteria = models.ForeignKey(Criterias)
    votes = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    total = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

So, there is some kind of duplication between `Companies -> PlaceTypes -> Criterias` and `Companies <- Ratings -> Criterias`. Is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need company as a foreign key in your Ratings model, which already has criteria, which has place_type that points to Companies, i.e. `Companies -> PlaceTypes -> Criterias -> Ratings`.

Comment: Are you sure? If I am correct, in this case Ratings are applied to PlaceTypes instead of Companies, i.e. all companies with the same PlaceType get the same Ratings

Comment: With the way you desribed it I thought that each of your PlacesTypes belongs to a company, but now it seems clear that you mean to describe a many-to-many relationship between companies and place types, in which case I would remove the company field from PlaceTypes and instead declare the following in your Companies model instead: `place_types = models.ManyToManyField('PlaceTypes')`